# PHP: Foreach Item in Array

Tags: php, foreach

Is there any way for me to have a foreach statement like:

```
foreach($item in $array1){
    //code goes here
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the arguments are the other way around, and you use `as` instead of `in`: `foreach ($array1 as $item) {...}`.

Comment: Is `foreach ($array1 as $item) { /* code goes here */ }` close enough?

Comment: I'm trying to make an array called blanks, and I'd like to use less code. The foreach statement would add a _ to the array for each letter in the secret word. I'm making hangman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
foreach ($array1 as $item) {
    // code goes here
}
```

Reference: [PHP foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)